# Is the phrase "our POTUS" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I saw somebody use this on twitter, but I had to do a second take because to me it doesn't make sense. If you expand the acronym you get "our President of the United States". It seems redundant if an American says it, since the it is already specified that the president occupies the American presidency. Is a non-American says it then it seems confusing, almost implying they have their own office named the President of the United States.

Comment: If we can reasonably refer to "our UN" or "our Milky Way [galaxy]," I don't see why "our POTUS" should pose any particular problem. In these instances, "our" emphasizes shared possession of the named thing by the speaker and his or her audience, without implying that other people may have a different UN or Milky Way galaxy.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the SAT Test? Or the SWAT Team? "Illogical" uses, including many with acronyms and initialisms, happen all the time. What ya gonna do--call the illogical patrol? Even in much more formal contexts, you'll see that language does not work according to norms of logic.

Comment: Yes it is grammatical: *Our* modifies nominal groups or "entities." POTUS is such a grammatical entity and, as such, it can be modified by *our*.

Answer (score 3):

In the current context it probably implies **ownership of responsibility**: *our* national shame, *our* dark secret, *our* troubling history supporting fascism.

Also consider that #notmyPOTUS is a hashtag on Twitter, calling out the illegitimacy of a election that awards the office to a candidate who received fewer votes.

In a specific conversation it might mean a favorite: "My POTUS is Abraham Lincoln, who is yours?"

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatically correct.

It is illogical, however, as it would imply that there may be more than one POTUS at any given time (i.e. there's ***our*** POTUS, but also ***your*** POTUS (a different person), and also ***their*** POTUS (yet another fellow or gal).

Answer (score 1):

POTUS is a nickname, not an official acronym. POTUS doesn't appear in the [government's style manual](https://www.govinfo.gov/collection/gpo-style-manual). Because it's a nickname, informal usage isn't ungrammatical.

Informally, "the POTUS" and "our POTUS" are only substitutes for "the president" and "our president." Strictly, "the POTUS" and "our POTUS" are like "the Donald" and "our Donald," an emphasized name.